# Editable Combobox not updating when empty

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, data-binding, combobox

I have an editable combobox here:

```
            <ComboBox IsEditable="True"
                  Text="{Binding Model.TNumber}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedT}"  ItemsSource="{Binding TList}"  
                  IsEnabled="{Binding EnableTComboBox}"/>
```

The combobox works, except when you backspace it and have it empty.
The box will default to the first value in the list. 
If I backspace it and leave the combobox empty, the variable TNumber will still contain the previously entered number.
Is there a way to have the variable to be empty?
TNumber is a short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure at which point you are checking the value of `TNumber`, but what you could do is set it's value in a `SelectionChanged` event handler:

```
private void comboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TNumber = (sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem as short?;
}
```

But this requires that you define `TNumber` as a nullable short (`short?`).

Alternatively, if you didn't want to allow a nullable `short`, you could use:

```
private void comboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var newValue = (sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem;
    if (newValue == null)
        TNumber = 0;
    else
        TNumber = (short)newValue;
}
```

Which first checks whether the new value is equal to null. If it is, then we set `TNumber` to 0 (or whatever value you need it to be).

---

While testing for this, I noticed that `TNumber` seems to be updated **after** the `SelectioinChanged` event fires, meaning that whenever you check the value of `TNumber` inside the event, it will contain the previous value.

One way of working around this is by adding this line to the top of the event handler:

```
comboBox.Items.Refresh();
```

Which sets `TNumber` to the new value. **However** this does not work when deleting the value from the `ComboBox`! (In this case, `TNumber` is again only updated after the `SelectionChanged` event handler).

I have no idea why this is, but I also tested it when working with `TNumber` as a `short?` with the same result.

```
private void comboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    comboBox.Items.Refresh();

    var value = (sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem; // Tested using short? with same result
    var x = TNumber;
}
```

Perhaps someone else could shed som light on why this happens, or at which point exactly the `TNumber` value is updated from the binding.